# What job is a “word processor”?

Tags: meaning

I don’t mean as a program like Microsoft Word, but as a job. If someone says, “I found a job as a word processor,” what is this person doing? (My first guess would be typing).

Comment: In my not so humble opinion, what this person is doing is speaking bad English.

Comment: They could also be trying to add a little bit of sarcasm by saying that their job is a menial one- simply typing, formatting or transcribing other people's words.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I commented because I had no context, the sentence might be set in present day. I've written a slightly longer answer to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about the following line from the recent NYT letter, *We Found Our Son in the Subway*: "I was an aspiring playwright working as a part-time word processor and Danny was a respected yet wildly underpaid social worker."

My reading was that he worked as a writer in various capacities, but in unfulfilling ways. 'Word processor' is used here to suggest a mechanical or menial wordsmithing job.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading an old sentence, or a sentence about someone's past, the job title might have a proper meaning. Twenty or thirty years ago, a word processor was a person who used Word (or WordPerfect or whatever) and was the new job title for what was previously called a typist. These days we expect people to mostly type their own documents, so there isn't a job title for people who type documents all day. (Data entry clerk is about numbers and short strings on forms, not letters and books.)

If the job being described has been found this year, I have no idea what the person means.

Answer (score 0):

A person whose job is that of a “word processor” could easily be a censor, a lexicographer, a translator, or a sign maker — and probably many other things as well  You cannot know for sure which thing they mean without further context.